# Use DocStrip (.dtx) with Unicode input

Tags: luatex, fontspec, unicode, dtx, docstrip

When I compile this file (`test.dtx`) with `tex test.dtx && latexmk -pdflua test.tex`, it doesn't support the UTF8 input.

```
%<*driver>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{\file{\jobname.tex}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{default}}}
\endbatchfile
%</driver>
%<*default>
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
äëïöü
\end{document}
%</default>
```

[image: screenshot]

The file DocStrip generates:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
^^c3^^a4^^c3^^ab^^c3^^af^^c3^^b6^^c3^^bc a
\end{document}
\endinput
```

While trying to solve this myself, I encountered this GitHub issue: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/34

In that issue, it's said that adding `\UseRawInputEncoding` to the top of the `.ins` file fixes this issue. But when I add `\UseRawInputEncoding` at the top of the `test.dtx` file (or right after `%<*driver>` on a new line), I get an error (undefined control sequence).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just DocStrip using `luatex`?

Comment: @JosephWright I completely forgot about this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

As [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) noted, the actual solution to my problem was to just use `luatex` instead of `tex`, i.e., to compile with

```
luatex test.dtx && latexmk -pdflua test.tex
```

---

After calling `tex -help`, I saw that there is a flag, `-8bit`, that'll `make all characters printable by default`.

Compiling the same `test.dtx` as above with `tex -8bit test.dtx && latexmk -pdflua test.tex` now worked as expected.

I'd still be curious if there's a solution that doesn't require a flag for the `tex` command.

---

What changed is that DocStrip now generated this document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
äëïöü
\end{document}
\endinput
```

The relevant part is that the file now contains `äëïöü` instead of `^^c3^^a4^^c3^^ab^^c3^^af^^c3^^b6^^c3^^bc a`. This then allows `fontspec` to print the desired characters.

Comment: how tex writes characters is not controllable within tex, so not controllable by latex, the external setting is the way, it can be made the default but on the system setup not from within docstrip